# Is it possible that session_cache_limiter('private'); affects on some browsers the persistence of session data?

Tags: php, session

I experience a problem that does not happen everytime with sessions data persistence.
I set the session.php file, which is called for every script, the main and some scripts called thru ajax queries, like following :

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 86400);
$samesite='lax';
$secure=(array_key_exists('HTTPS', $_SERVER) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS'])==='on')?true:false;
$httponly=true;
session_set_cookie_params([
    'lifetime'=>86400,
    'path'=>'/',
    'domain'=>$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
    'secure'=>$secure,
    'httponly'=>$httponly,
    'samesite'=>$samesite
]);
session_cache_expire(1440);
session_cache_limiter('private');
session_start();
```

Then for the login of a user on the site, I call first the login.php with a specific value in POST to get a salt and a RSA public key, while the server has to memorize RSA private key for the next query, that sends encrypted data to the same page for a different treatment.

Sometimes I get a custom error I set saying the RSA private key is not defined.

I tried commenting out the following: `session_cache_limiter('private');`, which seemed to fix my problem but I'm not sure about why.

Could someone explain this ?

[edit]
follow up to this issue :
the problem still occurs, on different environments (I tried linux debian with nginx/php-fpm and macos using macports' apache/php-fpm), but not every time, that is kind of surprising, and when it occurs, if I trace the session_id using error_log, I get a new session_id for each request, even if I did not use session_regenerate_id, which is used 'only' after a login. I suspect a logical error in the way I call session.php, but how to track it ?

I have detected that this error occurs systematically after deleting the browser's cookies and reloading the connexion page, and that after that if I wait the next asynchronous call of session.php, all comes back in order and works again.
Until now, I solve it only by calling asynchronously session.php at load time.

Comment: Because you probably actually want `private_no_expire`. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-limiter.php

Comment: Thank you, the two queries are done in a very short time lapse, do you mean that private sets the expiration to the time of the first query ?

Comment: Ah ok, I saw private has an expiration time in the past. Though, I wonder why sometimes it worked with private.

Comment: I just verified after  a while inside safari mobile, for example, I get the same bug with private_no_expire, then I removed the session_cache_limiter, and it worked.